# rake not working because "cannot find rdoc"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rdoc

This is probably part of a larger problem because I've been troubleshooting one problem only to encounter a new one. I finally deleted the whole directory and pulled down a fresh copy, but I'm still having the same problem:

```
$ rake db:migrate
Could not find rdoc-4.2.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
$
```

Running 'bundle install' does not fix the problem. When I look at the gemfile, it specifies rdoc 4.2.0, but gem list only has later versions. Attempting to 'gem install rdoc 4.2.0' results in:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '4.2.0' (>= 0) in any repository
```

Which I suppose means it's not available anymore. I suppose I could change the version in the Gemfile, but this is a shared repository and I don't want to bork it up for someone else.

What do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was on a different version of Ruby (1.9.3) than I had been before. I changed to a later version and ran 'bundle update'. My rake commands work now.